# запросы становятся в очередь для одной и той же сессии

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, сессия

Разрабатываю апишку на express и наблюдаю следующую проблему:

запросы с клиента на апишку становятся в очередь один за другим и выполняются только по окончании других, это если значения сессий не меняются а если значение сессий изменяется при каждом запросе то запросы выполняются паралельно, подскажите пожалуйста что необходимо предпринять что бы запросы не становились в очередь от разных клиентов.

Извините если не совсем грамотно описал проблему, просто может кто сталкивался с чем то подобным?

Comment: Разгружайте свои запросы, отправляйте задания в очереди, работайте асинхронно, если у вас возникает такая проблема, значит требуется оптимизация, либо поможет масштабирование проекта.

Comment: проблема в том что это происходит даже при двух одновременных запросах нагрузки как таковой нету

Comment: Хочу вас огорчить, но все запросы у вас всегда будут выполняться последовательно, это же nodejs, он однопоточный.

Comment: я понимаю просто такой момент что если без session midleware то запросы выполняются паралельно но если проверять сессию то они отрабатывают поочередно

Comment: @nezaetim выкладывайте проблемный участок кода, нужно больше подробностей